# Using EhCache as the main Datatasource instead of Database

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

Is it reliable to use ehCache as a datasource instead of a database ?

My business functionality will be to periodically collect information from a running application and store it in the Ehcache cache and then retrieve and display statistics about the collected information by querying the cache with EhCache Search API. The cache will only nee to keep the last 30-45 days of data.

What do you think about this approah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ehCache could be an acceptable solution - assuming TTI, TTL and other params are set according to your business needs. There shouldn't be any reliability issue per se. A SQL database affords options for transactional commits, complex queries and relational support which aren't provided of course of ehCache by itself.